# Ionic 1 call function from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem use ionic 1, I want to call function in First Controller from Second Controller, but I always get this error

```
TypeError: $rootScope.getData is not a function
```

anyone please help me to solve this problem, tonight I must collect my duty, this is my little script.

First Controller :

```
.controller('FirstController',function('SocketService',$scope, $rootScope){
  $rootScope.getData = function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```

Second Controller :

```
    .controller('SecondController',function('SocketService',$scope, $rootScope){
      $scope.callData = function() {
                $rootScope.getData('success');
            }
       $scope.callData();
    });
```

please anyone help me. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use a *service*.

```
.service('CommunFunctionsService', function(){
    var s = {};
    s.getData = function() {
        // do something
    }
    return s;
})

.controller('FirstCtrl', function(CommonFunctionsService, $scope){
    $scope.getData = function(){
        CommunFunctionsService.getData();
    }
})

.controller('SecondController', function(CommonFunctionsService, $scope){
    $scope.getDataToo= function(){
        CommunFunctionsService.getData();
    }
})
```

Comment: Correct approach, but the code this will throw SyntaxError. Check your syntax.

Comment: Of course, sorry for that! I edit my code from SO answer input directly so I missed autocompletion!

Comment: No, leave semicolons alone, not it's even two syntax errors. I meant `('CommonFunctionsService', $scope) ` part.

Comment: No problem, remove `;` otherwise your code will still throw syntax error.